# ListCollectionView, find the Type that AddNew() would create?

Tags: wpf, generics, reflection, listcollectionview, typeinfo

I'm having a custom control that 'can' have a ListCollectionView passed as ItemsSource, which I need the Child-Type of for Reflection Usage.

Now I could find the Type fromthe first element:

```
Type t = lcv.GetItemAt(0).GetType();
```

However that wouldn't work, when the Collection was empty.

It also works by calling `AddNew()`

```
Object o = lcv.AddNew()
Type t = o.GetType();
```

But I don't want to call AddNew just to create a dummy object as this causes bugs as site effect.

However if the Method "AddNew()" knows which type of an object to create, there must be a way to find out the actual Child-Type without having to create one.

I've used google, msdn as well as Try & Error and couldn't find how.

Some ideas?
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) to find the type contained in the collection

```
var type = lcv.SourceCollection.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Comment: Shame on me, I'm familiar with the GenericArguments and just didn't find it. Thank you alot!

Comment: @Steav  You should note that it will only work if `SourceCollection` is a generic type, otherwise you need to check of the type of the first element in the collection if the source collection is not empty.